# How to add index that covering all your WHERE requirements

Tags: mysql

I've a slow, according to my friend is it because there's no index covering all my WHERE requirements. If I run EXPLAIN, you'll see that the query is using: user_table_id index which is good but the query is additionally filtering on project_table_id and date_of_activity which are not a part of the index. So what i need is to create an Combined index on all 3 columns but not sure where to start or how to do it. let me know if you also have better idea to make this query more faster.

My query is :

```
SELECT time_activity_log.time_activity_log_id, time_activity_log.user_table_id, time_activity_log.project_table_id, time_activity_log.time_activity_id, time_activity_log.time_activity_log_id, time_activity_log.date_of_activity, time_activity_log.no_of_hours, time_activity_log.billable, time_activity_log.notes, time_activity_log.add_as_bugnote, time_activity_log.email_note, time_activity_log.make_note_private, time_activity_log.date_created, time_activity_log.date_updated 
FROM time_activity_log 
WHERE ( time_activity_log.date_of_activity >= 1412136000 AND time_activity_log.date_of_activity <= 1414814399 ) 
AND time_activity_log.project_table_id in (6,13,16,24,26,37,40,45,51,62,64,75,131,132,134,138,152,148,186,183,189,190,191,210,220,227,240,242,245,246,247,253,257,258,261,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,291,288,289,290,294,320,321,322,329,335,349,351,352,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,394,403,406,407,415,416,424,433,435,436,444,449,455,456,457,458,469,470,481,482,483,484,485,486,488,489,490,492,499,504,505,506,507,510,512,513,514,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,527,528,529,530,532,533,534,535) 
AND time_activity_log.user_table_id = 688 
ORDER BY time_activity_log.date_of_activity
```

So far when I do explain, I get :

```
id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : time_activity_log
type : ref
possible keys : user_table_id,project_table_id,idx_date_of_activity
key : user_table_id
key_len : 4
ref : const
rows : 2817
extra : Using where; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one index can be used at a time. If you want to make use of an index on all 3 columns, you have to make a composite index:

```
ALTER TABLE time_activity_log ADD INDEX (project_table_id, user_table_id, date_of_activity)
```

Comment: thank you so much Barmar for the reply, additional question if only one index can used at a time, what should I do with my current index? do I need to remove it or mysql can automatically detect what should use or should I tell mysql what to use? how?

Comment: I meant that a particular query will only use one index. But different queries will use different indexes, depending on their needs. You can get rid of the index on `project_table_id`; a prefix of a composite index can be used as an index on that column by itself as well, so the `project_table_id` index is redundant.